# What is year and model of my Diamondback?

Tags: identify-this-bike, diamondback

I have a Diamondback frame I'm guessing around 1984 or 85 serial # F4042789

Comment: Can you add a photo of the whole bike? It’s not easy to identify a bike even with a photo though, serial numbers aren’t much help either unfortunately.

Comment: The serial number is often pretty useless for this purpose.  Its not like a VIN on a car.  Since you already know its a diamondback then contact them at https://ride.diamondback.com/support  or try applying the myriad of options at https://www.quora.com/What-information-can-I-learn-from-my-Diamondback-bicycle-serial-number

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this thread](https://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=6063256), the bike in question matches "F4042" S/N portion with yours. According to messages, your bike was built by Formosa in Taiwan (F) in 1984 (4), so it's not Formula One, which was made in Japan. [This post](https://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=6063256#p6063256) mentions that "Viper, Pacer 500 & Super Streak were available that year", but [an archived copy of os-db](https://web.archive.org/web/20100323170800/http://www.os-db.net/content.php?157-Harry-Leary-3rd-Generation) reveals there were also Harry Leary, Super Streak, Super Viper and Viper.

To narrow the options down further, you can:

1. Visit all links above and see what matches your bike features the most.
2. Post photos here, especially serial number, dropouts, rear brake bridge. Full side shot would be good too.

I'm inclined to believe it's a 1984 Super Streak because 5 out of 8 serial number symbols match.